# How to send multiply push-notifications and show number of them

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification, multiplication

I have a server with some data and in my app I want to show this data via push-notification, so the problem is I didn't get how to cooperate notification number in status bar with my notifiсations. In my app I get notifications as `ArrayList` from my server. For each notification I should use a "Notification builder", in which I'll put notify fields like icon, name, desc etc, and at least I should call "NotificationManager.notify" for each of them, but how I can show that I've just gotten 3 messages for example in my status bar(one icon with indicator of 3, NOT 3 icons), and don't multiply a notification sound, but still show all of them when I open a status bar.

**My code**:

```
 public void sendNotifications(ArrayList<Message> messages){
    int notifyID = 0;
    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    for(Message message:messages){

        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
        PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0, notificationIntent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
        Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());

        builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, messages.media))
                    .setTicker("Got a new message")
                    .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                    .setAutoCancel(true)
                    .setContentTitle(message.titile)
                    .setContentText(message.text); 

        Notification notification = builder.getNotification();
        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, notification);
        notifyID++;
    }
}
```

## UPD

For more understanding what i want to i've added an images

-pic1 When i send notifications - icon shows me how much i got

[image: When i send notifications]

-pic2 When i opened a status bar it shows me all my notifies

[image: shows me my notifies]

It is possible to do that?

Comment: So basically you want one notification?

Comment: Yeah, but if i send 1 notification how i can show content of 3 messages? I need something like notification-stack or notification-list which will show 1 icon in statusbar, but still all notifications when i open a statusbar

Comment: So as Vang suggested in his answer, you can see that gmail example does the same thing in that. http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that - Combine 3 notification into one.

Either you create a single notification combining all the notifications or like this only.

It is not necessary that you will get 3 notifications. You can get 1 or 2 also.

I don't see the issue here. If there are 3 notifications, you will see 3 icons in the status bar.

Each icon represents an entry in the pull down notification bar- having one icon represent multiple entries wouldn't really make sense.

Comment: i guess you don't get what i mean, i want one icon like [this](http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/lessons/L0099/L0099_070.JPG) thats shows me a count of notifications i got, but if i open status bar it should show me all my notifications like [this](https://lh6.ggpht.com/2bZsMpvP_qLjYfTWt_a30BE29XdIJZ-A8DWySjhwVsHEHbdkTddCPaZU2cNmTgPEXhQ=h900). Whatever it was thank you for your answer

Comment: `        mNotificationManager.notify(notifyID, builder.build());
` this line itself will show the count in front of notification. Here enotifyID is the count variable

Comment: What you are asking is depreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Notification.Builder has method setNumber to set number of notifications. It's described in [Notification docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) in **Updating notifications** section.

Comment: will it work like [that](http://startandroid.ru/images/stories/lessons/L0099/L0099_070.JPG)?  it's show you one notification when you opened status bar, right? It's possible to show one notification icon in statusbar but 3 different notifications when you open it?

Comment: It will work like that http://developer.android.com/images/ui/notifications/updated_notification.png. I beleive you can simulate this behaviour by dismissing old notification and showing 3 different ones.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Big view notification.**
Check here : [Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html)

Comment: Yes, that's a limitation. :(

Answer (score 0):

Notification Id must be a constant. If notification id is different it will show as different notifications. So your code must be like this, declare ID and count as field variable:

```
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private int notificationCount = 1;
```

and change the method like this:

```
public void sendNotifications(ArrayList<Message> messages){
        int notifyID = 0;
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        for(Message message:messages){


            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this);
            // Adds the back stack
            stackBuilder.addParentStack(MainActivity.class);
            // Adds the Intent to the top of the stack
            stackBuilder.addNextIntent(notificationIntent);
            // Gets a PendingIntent containing the entire back stack
            PendingIntent contentIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0,
                    PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
            Resources res = getApplicationContext().getResources();
            Notification.Builder builder = new Notification.Builder(getApplicationContext());

            builder.setContentIntent(contentIntent)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                        .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, messages.media))
                        .setTicker("Got a new message")
                        .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                        .setAutoCancel(true)
                        .setContentTitle(message.titile)
                        .setContentText(message.text);
                        .setNumber(notificationCount++);

           mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
        }
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: kindly explain what is message class.... or gave me reference... i am not understand.... thanks...

Comment: @ExceptionLover : 'message' class is just a data class , which contain fields like name, title etc. Actually what we doing is save the data arrived from pushnotification to this class.

Comment: also it is good to save the notification count in preference or sqlite. Increment the count in preference on each notification arrival and if the user tap on the notification, clear the value to default.